# Setting log file path at runtime in Quarkus

Tags: logging, quarkus

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to set a log file path which can change as per current day.

Normally in our java programs, we use logback and store logs as below

**directory format** : yyyy/MM/dd
**log file name** : quarkus.log_yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm.log

This keeps rotating as per config. Pasting below snippet which is used to create log files

```
public class FileLoadeLogger extends
        ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender {

    @Override
    public void setFile(String file) {

        Date dNow = new Date();
        String logpath = System.getenv("APP_LOG_DIRECTORY");        
        
        if (logpath == null) {
            
            super.setFile("LOGS/<ProcessName>/"
                    + FormatDate.dateToCustomformatString(dNow,"yyyy/MM/dd")+ "/" + file + "_" +   FormatDate.dateToCustomformatString(dNow,"yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss")
                    + ".log"); // To change body of generated methods, choose
                                // Tools | Templates.
        } else {
            super.setFile(logpath + "/<ProcessName>/"
                    +FormatDate.dateToCustomformatString(dNow,"yyyy/MM/dd") + "/" + file + "_" + FormatDate.dateToCustomformatString(dNow,"yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss")
                    + ".log");
        }
    }

}
```

I want to implement the same in quarkus code, however I can't find any property which can set the directory path at runtime.
Setting any variation of 'yyyy' in simply created the directory of exactly the same string value.

Eg: Below config created directory with name '%d{YYYY}'

```
quarkus.log.file.path=%d{YYYY}/logging-test.log
```

I have tried below methods but unable to produce the desired result

1. Used different logging adapters. However it seems that values can not be overridden through java.
   [Quarkus logging adapters](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-adapters)
2. In memory config source but from reading it seems that it will set up the properties once and will not updated them again as required
   [Quarkus config source](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-extending-support#custom-config-source)

I am looking for advice on how to implement this logic in my process. If anyone has experience with this, could you please share an example or some tips on how to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a file suffix for log file rotation in your application.properties, e.g. with

quarkus.log.file.rotation.file-suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd

Quarkus would still log to quarkus.log, but at the beginning of the next day it would append yesterday's date to it and start a new log file.

See https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#quarkus-log-logging-log-config_quarkus.log.file.rotation.file-suffix

Comment: that's what we are using right now, however it doesn't solve requirement. Would writing a quarkus extension to override this parameter help?